# How to set instance members from constructor in Scala?

Tags: scala, constructor, instance, member

In Scala I need to do something like following code in Java does:

```
public class A {
  private String text;  
  public A(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

How can achieve that in Scala?

I know that I can use `class A(text: String) { ... }`, but this is only a very simplified example and not real case.

I have tried the following and it prints always null:

```
class A {
  var text: String = null
  def this(text: String) = {
    this()
    this.text = text
  }
  println(text)
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala classes have only one main constructor, and it's exactly what you define like this: `class A(text: String) { ... }`. All other constructors should call it at first and then do their own stuff.

All expressions in the body of the class are treated as body of the main constructor. So `println(text)` in you case is in the body of the main constructor. You call `this()` in your `def this(text: String)` constructor at first, so `println` is executed and only then you initialize `text` field.

---

From my point of view, main constructor can satisfy most of the real-life use-cases (especially with default and named arguments). So can you please elaborate on this and explain why you need the second one? Maybe we can find beter solution for the problem you are facing there.

---

#### Update regarding the comment

If you want to provide a set of optional arguments during construction time, then I recommend you to use `Option` instead of `null` values. So you can implement your `A` class like this:

```
class A(val a: Option[String] = None, val b: Option[Int] = None, c: Option[Double] = Some(2.0)) 

new A(b = Some(10))
```

All fields are now constant and have some default, but you can customize some of them. It's also possible that some combination of arguments are mutually exclusive, according to some business logic, for example. In this case it's reasonable to use several constructors. But even better solution can be to create several factory methods in companion object of the class and make constructor private. For example, if users of the class are allowed to provide either `a` and `b` or `c`, then you can write something like this:

```
class A private (val a: Option[String] = None, val b: Option[Int] = None, c: Option[Double] = Some(2.0)) 

object A {
    def apply(a: String, b: Int) = new A(Some(a), Some(b))
    def apply(c: Double) = new A(c = Some(c))
}

A("test", 1)
A(11.1)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I didn't know about fact, that all expressions in body of class are treated as if they were in constructor. And reason for which I asked the question was: I need to have multiple variables of various types in instance of class. I wanted to provide constructors for each allowed combination of them. Others would be null. Then in code I would be able to test if particular variable is null or has value and then do some action based on that.

Comment: It is certainly _not_ true that "All expressions in the body of the class are treated as body of the main constructor"! Only those expressions that are the right-hand side of non-lazy `val`s and `vars` and those at the top-level (_not_ method bodies) are part of the primary constructor.

Comment: @RandallSchulz in my definition, I make a distinction between expression and statement. for example `1 + 1` and `println("foo")` are expressions, but val, var and method definitions are  statements (they are part of the class structure and you can't actually call them expressions). Please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)#Expressions .

Comment: @tenshi: The part of a `var` or a `val` definition (you won't catch me using the term "statement" in regard to Scala...) that is to the right of the equal sign: a) _is_ an expression; b) _is_ part of the constructor body!

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
  var text: String = null
  def this(text: String) = {
    this()
    this.text = text
    println(text)
  }
}
```

or

```
class A(text:String=""){
  println(text)
}
```

or

```
class A(text:String=null){
  println(text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do that is :

```
    class A( text : String) {
       def this() = this("") // or null
   }
```

As Tenshi said, the default constructor is the `A(text : String)` and all other constructors, for instance `this()` must call it first.